# Creating matrix type cards for pdf in jspdf, integrated with sap ui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5, jspdf

Hope you are doing good.

My requirement is, to create matrix type cards, using jspdf, integrated with sap ui5.

So far, I have integrated, jspdf with SAP ui5 and generating pdf with cards.

But the layout of the cards, need to be customized as per attached screenshot.

[image]

I have used, a link,from jsfiddle, to create cards in jspdf which is posted in one of the comments.

////Begin of code

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
var pageWidth = 595;
var pageHeight = 842;

var pageMargin = 20;

pageWidth -= pageMargin * 2;
pageHeight -= pageMargin * 2;

var cellPadding = 10;
var cellWidth = 180;
var cellHeight = 70;
var lineHeight = 20;

 var startX = pageMargin;
 var startY = pageMargin;


 doc.setFontSize(12);

 function createCard(item) {

  var requiredWidth = startX + cellWidth + (cellPadding * 2);

  var requiredHeight = startY + cellHeight + (cellPadding * 2);

 if (requiredWidth <= pageWidth) {

 textWriter(item, startX + cellPadding, startY + cellPadding);

startX = requiredWidth;


 } else {


if (requiredHeight > pageHeight) {
  doc.addPage();
  startY = pageMargin;
} else {
  startY = requiredHeight;
    }

    startX = pageMargin;


    textWriter(item, startX + cellPadding, startY + cellPadding);

    startX = startX + cellWidth + (cellPadding * 2);
 }

}

function textWriter(item, xAxis, yAxis) {
doc.text(item.Name, xAxis, yAxis);
doc.text(item.Email, xAxis, yAxis + lineHeight);
doc.text(item.Company, xAxis, yAxis + (lineHeight * 2));
}


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
createCard(data[i]);
}
```

////End of code

PFA, screenshot of cards,getting generated.

[image]

Can anyone, please help me out, with the same?

Comment: Please post the relevant code to create a **[mcve]**

Comment: Paste your code, what have you tired?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Purushoth/jodfkz59/